# Selecting a column from different tables with the same name using Derived Tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to extract all the possible Airports with the name "BEIJING", but I keep getting an error of a duplicate column name, probably because of "Airplanes.name" and "Airport.name". How can I change my logic?

````
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT Airplanes.name, Airport.name
FROM Airplanes, Airport
WHERE Airplanes.Airport = Airport.id) RESULT
WHERE RESULT.name = "BEIJING";```
````

Answer (score 0):

Just add column aliases to your subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT Airplanes.name AS airplane, Airport.name AS airport
FROM Airplanes, Airport
WHERE Airplanes.Airport = Airport.id) RESULT
WHERE RESULT.airport = "BEIJING"
```

Note that you should really update to modern `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT Airplanes.name AS airplane, Airport.name AS airport
FROM Airplanes
JOIN Airport ON Airplanes.Airport = Airport.id) RESULT
WHERE RESULT.airport = "BEIJING"
```